# Запретить копировать URL страницы в буфер обмена

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

Как можно запретить копировать url адрес страницы? Может плагины какие есть или просто готовые решения? Плагины больше приветствуются, ибо возможно в плагине будет еще запрет на скачивание видео с сайта. Но если есть PHPm код или JS код который запрещает копировать адрес url, то тоже хорошо. За любую информацию буду очень благодарен

Comment: и зачем оно надо?

Comment: Дополнительная защита от скачивания курсов.

Comment: Проблема XY... Никак иначе.

Comment: Можно запретить скачивать, но не копировать URL.

Comment: Почему проблема XY? Название вопроса не соответствует описанию?

Comment: Спасибо, такой ответ тоже пойдет

Comment: Невозможно запретить ни  копировать ни скачивать. апомни простую истину: всё что попало на экран - уже скачано. Можно только усложнить жизнь посетителям сайта.

Comment: Все, что вы можете, это только запретить выделения. https://learn.javascript.ru/unselectable Однако, скопировать можно будет в инспекторе.  Запретить скачивать видео?  Если вы на сайте у себя отображаете видео, значит к нему уже есть доступ.

Comment: **ЗАЧЕМ** выкладывать в интернет то, что собираешься блокировать и запрещать? Может не надо делать тогда страницу на которой материал, а присылать материал по почте, после оплаты как и делают издательства??? или вести на страницу с проверкой авторизации???

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться функцией [alert](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert):

```
alert('Я запрещаю копировать url этой страницы!')
```

Comment: Хороший стёб :) Мысленно плюсую.

Comment: Я уже понял что никак, но спасибо за то что подняли настроение)

Comment: На самом деле есть способ. Вы можете спрятать настоящий урл за каким-нибудь другим, временным (например одноразовым), копирование которого ничего не даст. Но для этого нужен будет бекенд, который будет уметь обрабатывать эти урлы, следить за их одноразовостью и выдавать контент настоящей страницы, не выдавая настоящий урл

Comment: Почему же никак? Просто после загрузки страницы - подмените текущий `URL` на любой другой в адресной строке с помощью `js`, но без перезагрузки страницы.
Т.е пришел посетитель на `mysite.com` - после загрузки страницы Ваш `js`-скрипт меняет в адресной строке браузера `mysite.comi` на `disney.com` и если человек скопирует `URL` то уже не Ваш :)
Подробнее тут - `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/how-do-i-modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page`